# Configure max threads for @Retryable

Tags: java, spring-boot

We are trying to migrate from a job-based functionality to a retry mechanism. The problem is that the job-based implementation allows us to configure a thread pool which allows a maximum of [n] threads to run simultaneously, a configuration that we didn't find when we were using the `@Retryable` annotation.

Snippet for job:

```
public void startExecution(){
        Job job = createJob();
        Trigger trigger = createTrigger();
        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
        //the job will be triggered [3] times
        //the scheduler allows only [5] threads running simultaneously
        //=> calling the "scheduleJob()" > 5 times, only 5 threads will execute the job simultaneously
}
```

Snippet for retry:

```
@Async
@Retryable(maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(1000))
public void retryExecution(){
        //implementation
}
```

As you can see, there is no restriction in the retry mechanism and we can call the "retryExecution()" as many times as we want and it will run.

Comment: In spring `@Async` use a `TaskExecutor` configured by `@EnableAsync`. You can provide a more fine grain configuration by providing an [AsyncConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/6.1.5/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncConfigurer.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JEY's comment helped me realize that what I was searching for was wrong, the thread pool is configured not for the @Retry annotation, but for the @Async annotation. To configure a custom TaskExecutor, I found this very useful link: [What are the defaults in Spring @Async?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988341/what-are-the-defaults-in-spring-async)